Set Position Node
using a simple plane (2x2) I would like to set the position of point at edge position but the result is a plane 1x1 and not the same plane rotated of 90 degree . May be I do not know the use of set position node and capture attribute node.

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

Because each vertex is connected to 2 edges, not 1.
The values of the edges will be interpolated, and their mean values is exactly what you're getting.
In more detail:

"Set position" works on "vertices" (it's like a for each vertex, do...)
You set "capture attribute" for the "edge" domain

The software is saying:

wait! For this point you're giving me edge values? How am I supposed to do that?
Oh, I know! this vertice has 2 edges, let's take a mean from these two edges then.


To do this, you need to sample "one" edge instead.
(And because edges and vertices are not necessarily sequential, you need to sort the vertices first using face corners for that (the face corners are sequential for each face)


Thanks Daniel , I tried as your nodes but it is not exactly as I am looking for

I am sorry Daniel your nodes are OK !!!!! I made a wrong connection , now it works
